# Worksheet get_Range throws exception

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using C# to manipulate an Excel worksheet. The following two pieces of code should work the same, but one works and the other throws an exception. I wonder why.

This works:

```
oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range("A1","F1");
oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

This throws an exception:

```
oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1],oSheet.Cells[4,4]);
oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

Exception:

```
RuntimeBinderException occurred. "object" does not contain a definition for 'get_Range'
```

The `oSheet` is instantiated as follows:

```
Excel.Worksheet oSheet = new Excel.Worksheet();
```

Am I supposed to instantiate both differently?

Comment: It looks like, the "oSheet" is once typed as Worksheet and once as Object.

Comment: Agree with the above.  Can you post how oSheet is instantiated in both cases?

Comment: @Tcks, @DoctorMick, code posted

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It looks like the exception is thrown from the `oSheet.Cells[1, 1]` and `oSheet.Cells[4, 4]` used as arguments to `get_range`.

Applying the following, no exception will be thrown:

```
Excel.Range c1 = oSheet.Cells[1, 1];
Excel.Range c2 = oSheet.Cells[4, 4];
oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
```

So, it might be related to the `oSheet.get_Range` functionality. It receives an object as an argument, therefore it might try to invoke a `get_Range` method on the arguments to receive the internal cell, and the up-cast from `Range` to object done by the compiler might hide the method call.

If you need the cells definition by row/column - try using the above approach.

Comment: Which can be further shrinked into    oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1] as Excel.Object ,oSheet.Cells[4, 4] as Excel.Object);
    oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

Answer (score 29):

Use the Worksheet Range property instead.
For example, instead of

```
oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1],oSheet.Cells[4,4]);
```

use

```
oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[1, 1],oSheet.Cells[4,4]];
```

I was using the get_Range() method extensively when I leveraged off .NET 2. When I changed to .NET 4 Client Profile, I got this exception also. Replacing the get_Range() references with the Range property addressed this issue for me.

Comment: NirMH's solution worked for me, but I prefer this one (which also works)

Comment: Clearly, the problem is with framework 4.  I was on 3.5, and Get_range was working fine.  Now, under .net4, get_range wont work, and the use of Sheet.Range[] works fine

Answer (score 6):

For everyone who have this problem, much better use explicit conversion, rather than create new variables.

```
oRange = (Excel.Range)oSheet.get_Range((Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[1, 1], (Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[4,4]);
```

Answer (score 6):

I had upgraded my VS C# project from .Net Framework 3.5 to 4.5. 
Once I had upgraded successfully, I got this "object" does not contain a definition for 'get_Range' exception when trying to generate an excel report.

What I did is instead of using below code

```
range = xlSheet.get_Range(Cells[xlRow, xlCol], Cells[xlRow, xlCol]);
```

I rewrote to

```
range = xlSheet.Range[Cells[xlRow, xlCol], xlSheet.Cells[xlRow, xlCol]];
```

And it worked.

Comment: You have inconsistencies here in how you reference Cells - once with xlSheet - the other without.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above answers on .NET 5 but they do not work anymore.  Instead, following code works.

```
Excel.Range c1 = (Excel.Range)excelSheet.Cells[1, 1];
Excel.Range c2 = (Excel.Range)excelSheet.Cells[4, 4];
Excel.Range oRange = oSheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
```