# How to Customize Exported Excel from Console Application?

Tags: c#, console-application, export-to-excel

**How to Add custom Column headers ?**

Here is the code I use in Console Application.
It works correctly.

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\ExportFrmInventoryInvsupplierSupplier.xls";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                //creating the file contents
            }
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL\\SQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=Camo;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True");
            //SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL\\SQLSERVER1;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Camo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct Inventory.LocalSKU, Inventory.ItemName, Inventory.Price, Inventory.Price2,InventorySuppliers.Cost,Suppliers.SupplierName,InventorySuppliers.SupplierSKU FROM Inventory Inner JOIN InventorySuppliers ON InventorySuppliers.LocalSKU =Inventory.LocalSKU Inner JOIN Suppliers ON  InventorySuppliers.SupplierID=Suppliers.SupplierID where InventorySuppliers.PrimarySupplier='True' order by Inventory.LocalSKU", cn);
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(dr["LocalSKU"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["ItemName"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["Price"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["Price2"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["Cost"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["SupplierName"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["SupplierSKU"].ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Exported Successfully...!!!");
            }
            catch (Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }

        }


    }
```

Any Examples would be appreciated........................

Comment: You're just saving text into a file and adding xls on the end. You need to use Excel library if you want the appropriate spreadsheet functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478351/how-to-export-excel-from-dataset-or-datatable-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Yes. But Still Can't I add Column Headers in excel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the column names in the first row in the file try something like this

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
sw.WriteLine("LocalSKU\tItemName\tPrice\tPrice2\tCost\tSupplierName\tSupplierSKU");
while (dr.Read())
{
    sw.WriteLine(dr["LocalSKU"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["ItemName"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["Price"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["Price2"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["Cost"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["SupplierName"].ToString() + "\t" + dr["SupplierSKU"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: also , can I adjust columns according to data in that column?